# Change biblatex field format only when field has been replaced

Tags: biblatex

In my document, I want to have all abbreviations consisting of consecutive capitals to be set 90 per cent of the font size. I can do that manually in the text. But if it comes to journal abbreviations, I dont know how to achieve this for citations.

A `DeclareFieldFormat` would not work because the field `shortjournal` is only used to overwrite the `journal` field when present. And I dont want to set the `journal` field 10 per cent smaller in all cases but only in the cases when the full journal title is replaced by `shortjournal`.

In short: How can I re-format the `journal` field in citations but only in those cases where they have been replaced by `shortjournal`, as in my MWE?

I'm compiling with XeLaTex.

M(not yet)WE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\abk}{\textscale{0.9}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{AB,
         author    = {Author Beta},
         title     = {Title},
         shortjournal = {ABC},
         journal ={AllButCrash},
         pages = {1-23},
         year={2009}}
@ARTICLE{CD,
         author    = {Changed Director},
         title     = {Title},
         journal ={Boring Texts},
         pages = {23-42},
         year={2019}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-inote,sorting=nyt,bibencoding=utf8,citereset=chapter,citepages=separate,refsection=none,autocite=footnote,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false,date=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    %Shortjournal berücksichtigen      
      \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal]
      \step[fieldset=journal,origfieldval]
    }
    }
}

\begin{document}
A reference here.\footcite{AB} All Abbreviations in Capitals -- whom I call \abk{AAIC} -- should be in a font size 10 percent smaller. So that they don't look like THIS.\footcite{CD}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data substitution you are attempting leaves no trace that such substitution took place. So, without further information, on `biblatex`'s side we cannot know if a source map data change happened. But we could add such information by means of field annotations.

So, we could add one such annotation in the same map with:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    % Shortjournal berücksichtigen
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, final]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle+an, fieldvalue={=shortened}]
    }
  }
}
```

With that, the `journaltitle` field, when it has been substituted by `shortjorunal` in the source map, will also receive a field annotation `=shortened`, which we can then use as a conditional in the formatting directive:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{%
  \iffieldannotation[journaltitle]{shortened}{%
    \mkbibemph{\abk{#1}}%
  }{%
    \mkbibemph{#1}%
  }%
}
```

In full:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\abk}{\textscale{0.9}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{AB,
  author       = {Author Beta},
  title        = {Title},
  shortjournal = {ABC},
  journaltitle = {AllButCrash},
  pages        = {1-23},
  year         = {2009},
}
@Article{CD,
  author       = {Changed Director},
  title        = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Boring Texts},
  pages        = {23-42},
  year         = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=verbose-inote,
  sorting=nyt,
  bibencoding=utf8,
  citereset=chapter,
  citepages=separate,
  refsection=none,
  autocite=footnote,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  eprint=false,
  date=short,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    % Shortjournal berücksichtigen
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, final]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=journaltitle+an, fieldvalue={=shortened}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{%
  \iffieldannotation[journaltitle]{shortened}{%
    \mkbibemph{\abk{#1}}%
  }{%
    \mkbibemph{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
A reference here.\footcite{AB} All Abbreviations in Capitals -- whom I call
\abk{AAIC} -- should be in a font size 10 percent smaller. So that they don't
look like THIS.\footcite{CD}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another alternative would be not to do any data substitution, and handle the conditional directly in the relevant bibmacro, in this case `journal`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\abk}{\textscale{0.9}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{AB,
  author       = {Author Beta},
  title        = {Title},
  shortjournal = {ABC},
  journaltitle = {AllButCrash},
  pages        = {1-23},
  year         = {2009},
}
@Article{CD,
  author       = {Changed Director},
  title        = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Boring Texts},
  pages        = {23-42},
  year         = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=verbose-inote,
  sorting=nyt,
  bibencoding=utf8,
  citereset=chapter,
  citepages=separate,
  refsection=none,
  autocite=footnote,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  eprint=false,
  date=short,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}
     }
       {}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
    {\printfield{shortjournal}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shortjournal}{\mkbibemph{\abk{#1}}}

\begin{document}
A reference here.\footcite{AB} All Abbreviations in Capitals -- whom I call
\abk{AAIC} -- should be in a font size 10 percent smaller. So that they don't
look like THIS.\footcite{CD}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooops, you are right sorry, I didn't realise `shortjournal` was part of the default data model.

Comment: @moewe :-) And I was trying to grasp what you had in mind. As, in such issues, it is usually a matter of "how long" I take to agree with you, rather than "if".

Comment: @moewe I tried to incorporate the relevant information on how the source map works which was in your previous comment. I'm not sure I got it all though.

Comment: @moewe Btw, I did try the first solution with `\iffieldannotation{shortened}` (that is, without the optional argument `[journaltitle]`) and it didn't work. I have no idea why, as I would expect, from the documentation, that `\currentfield` would be grasped by the conditional.

Comment: I think that is due to the way the `journaltitle` field format is used: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2771 As you can see the format is not actually used to print a *field* (as in `\printfield`) instead it is used in a `\printtext` (which should have no `\currentfield`) to encompass several `\printfield`s. (Of course you can't know that without looking at the code, that is the drawback of using field formats for both `\printfield` and `\printtext` and is made worse by using an actual field name as format name.)

Comment: @moewe Ah, I get it, the `title`/`subtitle` handling. Thanks!

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks a lot! I preferred the second solution since it seemed neater to me to avoid the substitution at all. Additionally, the first solution failed to compile here due to errors at any citation, like : "Undefined control sequence A reference.\footcite{AB}". Alas, I did not find out where it comes from.

Comment: @shevek The first solution, as in the MWE used in the answer, runs error free for me here, and produces the document as in the screenshot. I don't know how you got to apply that in your own document. Anyway, if the second alternative works for you, that should be good enough.

Comment: @gusbrs Since it seems to fail at `iffieldannotation` (the footnote in the failed document looks like this: "...Beta. “Title”. In: ournaltitle]shortenedABC. ABC ...") it probably has something to do with different software versions. So, just for the record in case anybody else stumbles upon this: I'm using biber 2.7 and biblatex 3.7-r1.

Comment: @shevek That might well be the case, current biblatex version is 3.12. Thanks for reporting.